# What does "expr" do in MySQL's COUNT(expr) function?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count

Consider below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table;
SELECT COUNT(-2) FROM table;
SELECT COUNT(135392) FROM table;
SELECT COUNT(field) FROM table;
SELECT COUNT(field1 + field2) FROM table;
```

I am not clear on what `expr` actually does, or what it can be used for because all of the above SQL statements return the same result.  Example below:

```
+-----------+
| count(..) |
+-----------+
|     54542 |
+-----------+
```

MySQL's manual (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) does not go into very much detail on the `expr` part, other than using the `*` symbol

Comment: The doc link you mentioned is incomplete. This would be a complete one (also referenced in your source link): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT(<expr>)` counts the number of rows where `<expr>` evaluates to a non-`NULL` values.

Generally, it is not needed with an expression and would only be used on a single, `NULL`-able column -- or column that could be `NULL` due to an outer join.

Answer (score 2):

- `COUNT(*)` will count all rows
- `COUNT(expr)` will count the row if `expr` is `NOT NULL`

So `COUNT(expr)` could be less than `COUNT(*)` if `expr` contains NULL values:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(1), COUNT(col)
FROM (
    SELECT 'a' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b' UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL
) AS t(col)

-- 3    3    2
```

Answer (score 2):

Expr is short for expression, itself short for “some valid block of sql that results in a single value for this row when evaluated”

It could be a constant, a column, the result of a function call, variable assignment, case statement etc

```
—equivalent
COUNT(*)
COUNT(1)
COUNT(‘a’)

—count only males. If the group is 1000 in number and 600 are female, this returns 400
COUNT(case when gender = ‘m’ then ‘a’ else null end)
```

In supplement to the other answers, the `<expr>` may optionally start with the word DISTINCT in which case only unique occurrences of the referenced entity/expression/function result are counted

```
—in a set of 1000 animals, returns 1000
COUNT(gender)

—in a set of 1000 animals, 600 female, returns 2 (only values M and F exist in the group)
COUNT(distinct gender)
```